# Split PowerShell pipelines to separate files

Tags: powershell, pipeline

During testing, a function I'm creating is outputting both standard as well as verbose output. Right now, those both end up in the same log file. I would like to split them up.

Take this example:

```
Function Test-Output {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param ()
    Get-Process PowerShell, none
    Write-Warning "Test!"
    Write-Verbose "Test Verbose"
    Write-Debug "Test Debug"
}
```

If I run it:

```
Test-Output -Verbose -Debug
```

...I get the error-stream for the `none`-process (pipeline 2):

```
Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "none". Verify the process name and call the cmdlet again.
At line:4 char:1
+ Get-Process PowerShell, none
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (none:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

...my success-stream (pipeline 1):

```
Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    360      33    98736     109172   673     5.44   6220 powershell
```

...the warning-stream (pipeline 3): `WARNING: Test!`

...the verbose-stream (pipeline 4): `VERBOSE: Test Verbose`

...and the debug-stream (pipeline 5): `DEBUG: Test Debug`

So far, the only (crude) solution I have found to get each stream into its own file is this (I have replaced the `Out-File` with `Write-Output` for convenience here):

```
Test-Output -ErrorVariable ErrorVar -WarningVariable WarningVar -OutVariable OutVar -Debug -Verbose *> $Null
Write-Output "Error : $ErrorVar"
Write-Output "Warning : $WarningVar"
foreach ($Record in $Outvar) {
    If ($Record.GetType().Name -eq 'VerboseRecord') { Write-Output "Verbose : $($Record.Message)" }
    ElseIf ($Record.GetType().Name -eq 'DebugRecord') { Write-Output "Debug : $($Record.Message)" }
    Else { $Record }
}
```

When I try simpler solutions, I end up missing the error- and warning-stream (and I would still have to split them up using a `foreach` like above):

```
Test-Output -Verbose -Debug *> $OutVar
# $OutVar contains Pipeline(1), Verbose(4) and Debug (5)
# Error(2) and Warning (3) seem to be gone (not counting $error[0])

Test-Output -Verbose -Debug 2>&1 3>&1 *> $OutVar
# Error(2) and Warning (3) still gone

Test-Output -Verbose -Debug *>&1 > $OutVar
# Same Thing
```

So far, `Tee-Object` doesn't seem to do exactly what I want either.

So my question is: am I thinking too complex here, is there a simpler solution? If so, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a runspace.  Then you can handle the output and each of the stream outputs separately:

```
Function Test-Output {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param ()

$Code = {
$VerbosePreference,$WarningPreference,$DebugPreference = 'Continue'
Get-Process PowerShell, none
Write-Warning "Test!"
Write-Verbose "Test Verbose"
Write-Debug "Test Debug"
}

$newPowerShell = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($code)
$job = $newPowerShell.BeginInvoke()
While (-Not $job.IsCompleted) {}

[PSCustomObject]@{
  OutPut  = $newPowerShell.EndInvoke($job)
  Verbose = $newPowerShell.Streams.Verbose.ReadAll()
  Warning = $newPowerShell.Streams.Warning.ReadAll()
  Error   = $newPowerShell.Streams.Error.ReadAll()
 }

 $newPowerShell.Dispose()
}

$Result = Test-Output
```

That will return a custom object to $Result, with separate properties for each of the streams from the invocation.

Comment: Looks good, like making a wrapper around whatever I'm executing. I'll see if I can make `$code` a parameter. Strangely enough, the `Warning` appears empty, but if I call it, it'll show what it contains. Any idea where this comes from?  `Cannot convert null to type "System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference" due to enumeration values that are not valid. Specify one of the following enumeration values and try 
again. The possible enumeration values are "SilentlyContinue, Stop, Continue, Inquire, Ignore, Suspend".` (I really need to figure out how to do line breaks, double space doesn't work)

Comment: Never mind, I split them up and it works again: `$VerbosePreference = 'Continue' ; $WarningPreference = 'Continue' ; $DebugPreference = 'Continue'`. Maybe it's caused by my `WarningPreference`, which is already at `Continue`, while the other two are at `SilentlyContinue`.